# javascript animation effect time interval

Tags: javascript, intervals

There is a falling word, and I store its positions(x,y) and its value for separate arrays, and if I type the specific word, I remove all the values in three arrays.

I set interval time as 800, but the problem is deletion of the word corresponds to the interval time rather than it immediately deletes the following word.

I think this is because my draw() function is under update, which is under the influence of interval time, but I'm not sure how to maintain the draw of all the contents and erase immediately after I made input.

```
var intervalTime = 800;



setInterval(update, intervalTime); //appearance interval

function doKey (keyPressed) {
    if (window.event.keyCode === 13) { //if pressed enter
        var submission = document.getElementById('inputbox').value;
        var result = checkLetter(submission);
        if (result > -1) {
            //value deletion
            alpha.splice(result, 1);
            //positions deletion
            listx.splice(result, 1);
            listy.splice(result, 1);
            increaseScore('score');
        } else {
            console.log("this is an error");
        }
    document.getElementById('inputbox').value = ''; //return to the first step
    }
}

function draw() {
    for (i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        listy[i] += spdY;
        ctx.fillText(alpha[i],listx[i],listy[i]);
    }
}

function update() {
    if (document.getElementById('life').innerHTML == 0) {
        alpha = []
        listx = []
        listy = []
        console.log("fail");
        endoftheGame();
    } else {
        increaseLevel();
        //console.log(alpha);
        //console.log(listx);
        //console.log(listy);
        spdY = 50 + 5*(document.getElementById('score').innerHTML/10);//speed
        lifeDeduction()
        getLetter();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your `draw()` function from the `doKey()` function with `ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);` called before it to redraw the screen. This way your screen updates immediately but other parts of the `update()` function do not execute.